# using pandas dataframe to merge based on three columns from multiple files

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I would like to merge using `pd.merge` almost 10 files each file has data something like this,

```
chrom   start   end name    score   strand  splice_site acceptors_skipped   exons_skipped   donors_skipped  anchor  known_donor known_acceptor  known_junction  genes   transcripts
4      3487839 3491240  JUNC00148541    101 -   GT-AG   2   1   3   DA  1   1   1   Tmem68  ENSMUST00000029891,ENSMUST00000108388,ENSMUST00000154922
4      3489293 3491240  JUNC00148543    1   -   GT-AG   1   0   1   DA  1   1   1   Tmem68  ENSMUST00000029891,ENSMUST00000108388,ENSMUST00000154922
```

I have used merge in the past using `pd.merge(df_a, df_b, on='gene', how='outer')` passing only one column, here I would like merge them based on the chrom,start and end and strand.

my new df would look like

```
chrm:start-end(strand) score_file1 score_file2 ...file10 gene_name splice_site acceptores exon_skipped donors_skipped...transcripts
```

if there is no match `how='outer'`i presume will enter a NaN value. what would be best way to go about this with less memory usage?

```
path = r'/Users/PycharmProjects/'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*_bed.txt"))
print(all_files)
df1 = pd.read_table(all_files[0])
df2= pd.read_table(all_files[1])

concatnated_df = pd.merge(df1,df2, on=['genes','chrom','start','end'], how='outer')
print(concatnated_df.head(n=5))
```

Any help appreciated!

updated simplified question:

```
chr start end score strand gene
1   20    30  50    -      abc1
2   40    50  50    +      cdf1
```

10 csv files with such data, merge them based(exact match) on chr, start end and gene
new df

```
chr start end score_file1 score_file2..file10 strand gene
1   20    30  50  20 40   -      abc1
2   40    50  50  30 50   +      cdf1
```

Comment: You can pass the columns as a list: pd.merge(df_a, df_b, on=['gene','chrom','start'], how='outer')

Comment: that worked i guess , but the problem is its appending the whole headers as well     chrom start end name_x score_x strand_x splice_site_x acceptors_skipped_x exons_skipped_x donors_skipped_x anchor_x known_donor_x known_acceptor_x known_junction_x genes transcripts_x name_y score_y strand_y splice_site_y acceptors_skipped_y exons_skipped_y donors_skipped_y anchor_y known_donor_y known_acceptor_y known_junction_y transcripts_y

Comment: is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Sorry I probably don't completely understand the question... What are you planning to do with final result? Concatenating (union) and then group by might be a better option http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: hi thanks for replying, i have updated my question, sorry for confusing

Comment: I am still not able to figure out the right approach, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly you want to get rid of extra columns, then you can select the columns you are interested in and instead of passing the whole thing in df just add select columns...like: concatnated_df = pd.merge(df1[['chr','gene','start','end','score']],df2[['chr','gene','start','end','score']], on=['gene','chr','start','end'], how='outer',suffixes=['file1','file2'])

Comment: the suffixes argument let you customize the suffix for the score field which repeats in all dataframes

Comment: I need to match the rows in first three columns and then add the scores (column) from each file for almost 10 files. scores would be different for each row in each file.

Comment: I hope below answer helps...

Answer (score 0):

```
dfs = [df1[['chr','gene','start','end','score']],
       df2[['chr','gene','start','end','score']],
       df3[['chr','gene','start','end','score']],
       df10[['chr','gene','start','end','score']]] 
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=
                  ['gene','chr','start','end'], how='outer'),dfs)
```

Comment: tried the above code not able to append columns from each df I just got 4 columns with chrom genes start end score